# Can we distinguish Actor Termination in terminated Message?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I am handling the termination of an actor in my program. But at some point when the actor's task is completed, I am gracefully shutting it down(**By sending PoisonPill message**). I want to skip the handling of termination of the actors which I am purposefully shutting down. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: How exactly you're handling the termination? Via `watch` and reacting to actor lifecycle events?

Comment: @J0HN I am getting the properties of the actor that i have saved it while processing.

Comment: I think props doesn't give you anything (except ability to create another copy of the actor) - could you post relevant parts your code to make it clear?

Comment: My question is can i distinguish between a normal gracefull termination of an actor and a termination because of some error?

Comment: As far as I know - no, but during "normal" graceful shutdown actor can notify others of shutting down - and those "others" might do something about it - like stop watching it to not receive termination message

Comment: If an actor gets terminated the watching actor get terminated message in both the cases (graceful shutdown or forceful termination). I want to catch only when the actor is forcefully terminated.